# How to pass a parameter that includes an exclamation mark (!) to a function

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh

I have a ZSH function called **my_function** which receives some parameters. I would call the function and pass some parameters which may include an exclamation mark infront of them, for example:

```
$ my_function !param1 param2 param3
```

or

```
$ my_function !apples bananas cherries
```

However I am receiving the error:

```
zsh: event not found: param1
```

How do I pass a parameter that has an exclamation mark infront such as **!apples**? I would prefer not to use quotes or escape characters if possible (I just want all text coming after the word **my_function** to be passed as parameters). Thanks

Comment: Do you use zsh or bash?

Comment: I am using zsh but the problem seems to happen for both